# Error AOT building a custom component decorator - Angular 5

Tags: angular, build, decorator, angular-aot

I've build a custom component decorator, as described here [Inheritance of Angular 5 components with overriding the decorator properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504711/inheritance-of-angular-5-components-with-overriding-the-decorator-properties/52817521#52817521).

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    export function ExtendedComponent(extendedConfig: Component = {}) {
        return function (target: Function) {
            const annotations = target['__annotations__'] || [],
                  parameters = target['__paramaters__'] || [],
                  propMetadata = target['__prop__metadata__'] || [];

            if (annotations.length > 0) {
                const parentAnnotations = Object.assign({}, annotations[0]);

                Object.keys(parentAnnotations).forEach(key => {
                    if (parentAnnotations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (!extendedConfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            extendedConfig[key] = parentAnnotations[key];
                            annotations[0][key] = '';
                        } else {
                            if (extendedConfig[key] === parentAnnotations[key]){
                                 annotations[0][key] = '';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return Component(extendedConfig )(target);
        };
    }
```

In use:

```
    @ExtendedComponent({
        selector: 'app-auto-complete',
    })
    export class AutoCompleteComponent extends AutoComplete {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        ngOnInit() {
        }
    }
```

It work perfectly in dev mode, but when I try to build it I get the following error:

```
    ERROR in : Can't bind to 'suggestions' since it isn't a known         property of 'cds-auto-complete'.
    1. If 'cds-auto-complete' is an Angular component and it has 'suggestions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'cds-auto-complete' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("...
```

I've tried adding the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA & NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, but it doesn't help. Any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Custom decorators like these do not work in AOT, because the compiler is looking for classes which have the `@Component` decorator. To fix this you have to add the `@Component()` decorator to the class as well (and remove the `Component(extendedConfig)(target)` in your custom decorator):

```
@Component({...})
@ExtendedComponent({
    selector: 'app-auto-complete',
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent extends AutoComplete {}
```

But I suppose this kinda defeats the purpose of your extended component.

You can see the complete github issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16023). This is not the exact same issue, but it is the same cause

Comment: Thanks. The main reason I want to use a custom decorator, is so that I can use the parent (external library) components inline template. Do you know of any other ways I could do this?